# Как правильно повесить java script событие на кнопку yandex donate?

Tags: javascript, yandex-metrika-api

Привет.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, заказчик попросил повесить "Цель" из яндекс метрики на кнопку, яндекс денег.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

одним из вариантов добавления цели является создаение js события onClick на данной кнопке.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(".b-button__input").click(function(){
  yaCounter########.reachGoal('DONATE');
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Но возникло одно но, данная кнопка добавляется на сайт в виде iFrame, и при добавлении делает не возможным взаимодействие js с DOM этой кнопки.

Как мне кажется это достаточно распространенный кейс когда нужно увидеть как часто посетители нажимают кнопку. 
Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему, или воpможно есть способ взаимодействия с iFrame через js который мне пока к сожалению неизвестен.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi, нельзя так сделать, по крайней честными способами, не эксплуатируя уязвимостей. Это базовые ограничения безопасности. Если б это как-то работало, то представьте, например что вы загрузили gmail во фрейме и отправили своим скриптом 100500 писем куда хотите.

Comment: @ru_volt Да я понимаю что яндекс вставляет кнопку в iFrame исключительно из целей безопасности, похоже единственный вариант, на мой взгляд, остается это отлавливать редирект после оплаты.